# How do I get Drupal7 to wait for a response from the smtp server before sending system mail?

Tags: drupal-7, smtp, debian

I have exim4 which is running fine related to most of the servers that send mail through it.  This is a server that handles mail from web-apps. It has no standard users and nobody but machines in the LAN check it for mail or smtp mail out to it.

A week ago, it stopped accepting  mail from 2 drupal7 machines on debian.  At the time, I had gotten no complaints from the #2 machine, so I just was troubleshooting the connection between Drupal-7-01 and mailserver.org.  Since it appeared to be failing at the drupal machine, I installed exim4 on that machine and configured it as a relayer to a smarthost (mailserver.org).  The result was that the drupal-7-01 machine's system messages started to be delivered to my external mailbox.  Cron started sending me messages when it ran.  Before, these messages were held in a local queue and I would look at them occasionally.  This means that the 2 servers are working fine together at a system level.  However Drupal7 mails were failing to be sent.

The error was that the sender was not waiting before sending the messages to the smtp server at mailserver.org.

I have much of the error messages and so on up here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12158322#post12158322

I still don't have working mail from the drupal machines.
I think it might work to make support@drupal-7-01.net a local user to that machine and have the drupal instance send to that machine's exim4 server which in turn will send to the mailserver.org, have local machine fqdn stripped off and mailserver.org's fqdn installed.  This is how the local cron message is getting to me from that machine, so it should be able to work.

Comment: I tried adding a support user on drupal-7-01 as in support@localhost since I knew that mailserver was communicating properly with the main mailserver.  The local mailserver took the test message and sent it on to the main mailserver as a local user sending a message to the external world.  Worked!  The test message arrived at the expected remote recipient.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Drupal.  The fact that anti-spam measures also bite amateur mail client authors in the rear is considered acceptable collateral damage.